# pixel.gif, why do people use it?

Tags: html, pixel

Just a simple question, why is pixel.gif usefull? And why should you use it or why not?

Comment: Do you mean using pixel.gif in web development/design?

Comment: What do you mean by pixel.gif?

Comment: Usually because they're not knowledgeable with any of the modern ways of doing web layouts.

Comment: @Pekka http://cognition.happycog.com/article/single-pixel-transparent-image-seeks-gainful-employment

Comment: It is not that useful as what you think it is. There are modern ways. Pixel gif is just used for a very specific purpose, like PowerPoint Presentation. And also, what you are asking is not a real question--that is, it seems atrocious to ask a very general question to a very specific answer.

Comment: @Ivan nice link! @Neigyl I somewhat disagree. It's an okay question to ask IMO. It's just poorly worded in its current form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pixel gifs (often called shim.gif) were used in older web designs (i.e. older than, say, 5 years ago) to provide a space in page or table layouts where a better understanding of robust CSS was lacking or if browser differences (typically between IE and Netscape) made life too complicated.

They should be considered a relic of the past and would not be seen in a professional CSS layout in today's web design. However it is still possible that older pages that haven't been maintained over the years will still have table-based page layouts with pixel shim images to provide some artificial spacing for columns.

In short, you should not use them unless an image is required for non-javascript statistics gathering for your site.

Comment: For HTML in emails: note that MailChimp recommends to "Use tables and shim.gifs", see [About HTML Email](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/about-html-email) See also Tom Gerencser's answer

Answer (score 5):

Shim .gif's are transparent images typically 1x1 pixel in size. As noted above, these images should not be used for spacing in modern web browsers (2013) as CSS does a superior job of layout.

However, email marketing campaigns continue to leverage them for a couple of reasons:

1. As an asset that can be used for marketing analytics (i.e. email opened?)
2. For spacing issues arising from using tables for layout in email.

Email clients do not universally support CSS so it is best practices to code your newsletters and application alerts as if it were 1996.

Answer (score 2):

Because through history, browsers have had various issues with rendering empty elements, and sizing elements correctly. Using a transparent pixel image and stretching it as content was a fairly universal method to get an element to resize correctly, and the pixel could be put in  a hyperlink ending up with a transparent, clickable area on any browser.

Nower-days, browsers and browser technology have improved greatly, and I think it has been years since I used a pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Just because of IE. IE 7-8 cant properly work with background png + opacity. There are only one way to fix it:

```
background: url("/images/blank.gif") no-repeat, url("/images/howto.png") no-repeat;
background-color: transparent !important;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled="true", sizingMethod="crop", src="/images/howto.png");
zoom: 1;
```

IE is not a browser. I cant say anything except bad words about this program. I have now a great amount of bugs marked IE 7 ONLY, IE 8 ONLY, IE 8 in compability mode with IE 7 ONLY, IE 9 ONLY and IE 10 ONLY

Users, please! Drop windows and all its delirium to the hell. Use GNU/Linux!